# Why Json request return missing SyntaxError: missing ; before statement in a valid JSON response

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, jakarta-ee, jsonp

I do not understand why I get a syntax error, as everything seems to be fine when I return the controller method.

This is the ajax request:

```
        $.ajax({
        url : contextPath +'/test/school/country.action?getById=&countryId='+1,
        async : false,
        type : 'post',
        success : function(data,status) {
         var countryJSON = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
         alert(countryJSON.clave);
    },
       error : function (data, status, e) {
            alert(e);
        },
        cache : false
    });
```

And the valid JSON response:

```
{"clave":"USA","claveDesc":"USA - United States of America","desc":"United States of America"}
```

the error is not in the parsing `jQuery.parseJSON(data);`. The request always invokes the error method (in the ajax request) when returning from my controller's method. I thought it was the browser, but the same thing happens in chrome and firefox.

already try to indicate the type of data expected by the ajax invocation, but continue with the same error.

My mind is already completely cloudy, I appreciate any help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you inspected the API call in the Network tab and confirmed it is coming back with a 200 status code?

Comment: Yes,  the ajax  response  coming back with  a 200 status code

Comment: not hard and fast but , `dataType : 'json',
    contentType : 'application/json',` and i suppose you are sending response json with object mapper from servlet